# How do I detect undefined variables within an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, undefined

I am currently working on a project where some records for wpm are displayed. It currently works so that if any elements in the array are undefined it sets them to `""` so that on output they are not displayed. My version is clunky and too big, and I was wondering how I would make it smaller with a function.

**Code:**

```js
var fifteenSecond = `Your 15s highscore: ${maxesTime[15]}wpm`
var thirtySecond = `Your 30s highscore: ${maxesTime[30]}wpm`
var sixtySecond = `Your 60s highscore: ${maxesTime[60]}wpm`

  if (maxesTime[15] === undefined) {
    fifteenSecond = ""
  } else if (maxesTime[30] === undefined) {
    thirtySecond = ""
  } else if (maxesTime[60] === undefined) {
    sixtySecond = ""
  }

console.log(`${sixtySecond}}\n${thirtySecond}\n${fifteenSecond}`);
```

Thanks in advance,

Any and every answer is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a `for` to check every property `i` in `maxesTime`. In this way if you add a new "max time" (*e.g.* "45"), you don't have to change your code.

```js
let maxesTime = {
  '15': 100,
  '30': null,
  '45': undefined,
  '60': 400
};
for (let i in maxesTime) {
  if (maxesTime[i]) {
    console.log(`Your ${i}s highscore: ${maxesTime[i]}wpm`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my aproach:

```js
function getRecord(seconds, maxesTime) {
  return maxesTime[seconds] ? 
    `Your ${seconds}s highscore: ${maxesTime[seconds]}wpm`
    : '';
}
```